# jquery mobile loading widget, how to call and close

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

On my jQuery mobile website I have an image where I'm calling a JS function on image click. That function is using AJAX goes to the MVC controller and returns a partial view.

I want to use the jQuery mobile loading widget on image click to display `loading...` and on function success, close that loading widget. How do I do that?

```
<img onclick="DisplayData();" src="/Content/images/image.png" />
```

```
function DisplayData(){
    // ...
    success: function (result) {
        $("myId").html(result);                  
        // close loading widget 
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your js function DisplayData call show loading widget before ajax call.

```
function DisplayData() {
   $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.ajax({...}
```

and on success hide loding widget

```
success: function (result) {
           $("myId").html(result);
           $.mobile.loading('hide');
    ...
```